# Compare 2 data sets based on matching values in a column

Tags: r

I am trying to compare data in one dataset against another, to do this every time I see a code in my first dataset I wish to check the 2nd dataset and if that code appears in there check of the values of the other columns match.

```
df1
code      count     length     width
13525      64        5          10
13456      20        10         20
13455      22        10         25
12334      10        2          5
12333      12        5          5
13234      18        8          10
```

Now I wish to check the 2nd dataset to check the count, length and width columns are correct for each code. Here for example I know that code 12333 isn't in the 2nd dataset which isnt an issue, what I am worried about is any of the other columns being different.

```
df2
code      count     length     width
13525      64        5          10
13456      20        10         22
13455      22        11         25
12334      10        2          5
13234      18        8          10
```

What I'm trying to get is a 3rd datafame of the values that are different. I'm not entirely sure the best way to go about this, I'm struggling to match the codes mainly. For example;

```
codes_that_dont_match
13456      20        10         22
13455      22        11         25
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```
> setdiff(df2, df1)
   code count length width
1 13456    20     10    22
2 13455    22     11    25
```

or

```
x1 <- do.call(paste, df1)
x2 <- do.call(paste, df2)
df2[is.na(match(x2, x1)), ]
```

which gives

```
   code count length width
2 13456    20     10    22
3 13455    22     11    25
```

Answer (score 1):

is it ok

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- data.frame(
  code = c(13525, 13456, 13455, 12334, 12333, 13234),
  count = c(64, 20, 22, 10, 12, 18),
  length = c(5, 10, 10, 2, 5, 8),
  width = c(10, 20, 25, 5, 5, 10)
)

df2 <- data.frame(
  code = c(13525, 13456, 13455, 12334, 13234),
  count = c(64, 20, 22, 10, 18),
  length = c(5, 10, 11, 2, 8),
  width = c(10, 22, 25, 5, 10)
)

# Compare filter for differences
differences <- df1 %>%
  inner_join(df2, by = "code") %>%
  filter(count.x != count.y | length.x != length.y | width.x != width.y) %>%
  select(code, count.x, length.x, width.x)

# Rename the columns in the differences dataframe
colnames(differences) <- c("code", "count_df1", "length_df1", "width_df1")

# Print the differences
print(differences)

code count_df1 length_df1 width_df1
1 13456        20         10        20
2 13455        22         10        25
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by others, the differences can be detected with `anti_join`.

```r
library(dplyr)
df1 = 
  read.table(text = 
        "      code      count     length     width
             13525      64        5          10
             13456      20        10         20
             13455      22        10         25
             12334      10        2          5
             12333      12        5          5
             13234      18        8          10",
        header = T)


df2 =
  read.table(
    text =
      "code      count     length     width
        13525      64        5          10
        13456      20        10         22
        13455      22        11         25
        12334      10        2          5
        13234      18        8          10",
    header = T
    )
```

How you use the function would depend on what differences you want to find.

The rows in `df1` with no match in `df2`

```r
df1 |> 
  anti_join(df2,by = names(df1))

#    code count length width
# 1 13456    20     10    20
# 2 13455    22     10    25
# 3 12333    12      5     5
```

Or the rows in `df2` with no match in `df1`

```r
df2 |> 
  anti_join(df1,by = names(df1))

#    code count length width
# 1 13456    20     10    22
# 2 13455    22     11    25
```